# Upgrade to final from Public Beta?

Tags: upgrade, macos, beta-seed-program

I'm currently on the public beta of El Capitan, how do I upgrade to the final version of the new OS?

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to upgrade. OS X 10.11 GM and final release are the same according to Apple and once 10.11.1 is released both the GM and final release will update to it.

Answer (score -1):

The safe way:
Boot into Recovery HD, erase the drive, and restore from your Yosemite backup (if you have one). Then download the installer and upgrade.

I wouldn't recommend just downloading the installer and updating, as bugs could be carried over.